# Populating data for join table, by defining my own criteria in has_many association (with using the other table's columns too)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have Stock and Calving model tables. **Stock.rb** has this

```
has_many :calvings
has_many :calves, class_name: "Stock",through: :calvings
```

and in Calving.rb:

```
belongs_to :stock
has_many :calves, class_name: "Stock", foreign_key: "mother_id"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :calves
```

When I edit the carving record, I want the controller to populate the data from the Stock model by a given criteria. I need to run this sql when I use **@calving.calves**

> SELECT * FROM STOCKS, CALVINGS WHERE STOCKS.MOTHER_ID =
>   CALViNGS.STOCK_ID AND STOCKS.BIRTHDAY = CALVINGS.CALVING_DATE

Is it possible? If *yes*, what should I write into the Calving model's has_many association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to do, but if you need something to happen on an action, simply use a callback: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: The saving of the model works fine, I've only problems with the populating of the data, when I want to update the model.I try to create the form via the form builder (in the controller's edit method), and when i use the command: **@calving.calves.build** it returns all calves data for the calving record. I want to filter these data (for example in the has_many association), to return only the calves, where calving.birthday==calves.each.birthday. (I don't want to put this where clause in the edit method, I'd like to solve it via has_many. (@SherwynGoh, @FCStrike it's the answer for both of you)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this

```
class Calvings < ActiveRecord::Base
after_save :update_calves
```

Either

```
def update_calves
 calves.each do |calf|
   calf.attribute = **
   calf.save
 end
end
```

OR

```
def update_calves
  calves.update_all( "attribute = value, attribute1 = value1 ")
end
```

Comment: You missunderstood me. Saving works fine, when I want to edit the model, I want the nested models to show up, but I have a criteria for that, I tried this in **calvings_controller/edit**:     **@calving.calves = Stock.where(birthday: @calving.calving_date, mother_id: @calving.stock_id)
    @calving.calves.build**
The data appeared in the form, but when I saved, it created a new record for every nested model, not updated the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for adding a second answer, I need 50 rep to comment so the site kinda bugged out on me when I tried to reply.

Essentially you're asking how to override the default fields_for behavior, if I'm understanding you correctly. Doing this is actually rather straightforward.

Looking at the documentation

```
fields_for(record_name, record_object = nil, fields_options = {}, &block)
```

In normal cases you would use something like the following:

```
<%= f.fields_for :nested_object do |n| %>
```

Which would create form fields for every :nested_object under the parent. This is because rails is intelligent and will assume that you want everything. To override this behavior, we simply pass an array into the second parameter containing only those objects we want fields for.

For example:

```
<%= f.fields_for :nested_object, @custom_array_with_nested_objects do |n| %>
```

This will only create fields_for the objects in @custom_array_with_nested_objects.

With all that in mind, I would begin by creating a method in your model which returns an array containing the calves you want. In your controller, make an instance variable which captures those calves. Finally in the view, your fields_for should contain that instance variable as I described above. This should accomplish what you're looking to do.

Comment: No problem dude. So I tried what you mentioned, I created `@calving_filtered = Stock.where(birthday: @calving.calving_date, mother_id: @calving.stock_id)` in my controller, and put `<%= f.fields_for :calves, @calving_filtered do |builder| %>` in the view. When I submit the form, it creates a new nested model with the changed data, it doesnt update the old one.

Comment: I suspect you didn't allow the ids through your strong parameters. The controller is preventing the id from going through, the update_attributes method is seeing the objects as new objects due to the lack of specified id, and new nested objects are being created.

Comment: Hm, and how can I allow the Id? I use the same form for new model,and for edit too.

Comment: Each nested object with a parent has an object_id parameter which links it to the id of its parent. In your strong parameters you have to allow :object_id along with all the other nested object's parameters. For instance, if I have a model Fruit which belongs_to Basket, every fruit object will have a basket_id attribute. In the Baskets controller, I would include :fruits_parameters[:basket_id] in the strong params.